# Does the following code illustrate async functionality?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, shell, asynchronous

I would assume that if I run the following code in my node console.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test', function(err, db){
    if (err) throw err;

    db.collection('allClasses').findOne({}, function(err, doc){
        //Print the result
        console.dir(doc);

        //close the DB
        db.close();
    });
});

setTimeout(function(){
    console.dir("10 Milliseconds!");
}, 10);

setTimeout(function(){
    console.dir("100 Milliseconds!");
}, 100);
```

That if I consistently (10 out of 10 times) get the following output:

[image]

That this illustrates that not only does the mongo query take between 10 and 100 ms to 
 return my data, but that my node console executes my code in an asynchronous fashion.

**Question:** Is this correct?

*I have one alternate question.*

If I wait for a very long time to execute this script, let's say 20 minutes, leaving my mongod.exe running. And then run the script. Sometimes I get the following output.

[image]

I can understand the data return coming in last, I'm assuming because it takes longer than 100 ms for some reason probably to do with connectivity or since I waited so long it takes longer because mongod is idle or something along those lines....

**Question 2:** Why would the message function that is timed out longer show up first?

I know there has to be a silly reason.

Comment: 10 and 100 ms is really low interval, you should increase it to view more accurate data, your PC can lag in that time that can describe your `Sometimes`.

Comment: Ok I can understand that, but given the conditions and the test ran I have done it over 100 times now. Considering my machine was never any different than it is now. Does this mean on average (or a majority of the time without extenuating circumstances) is this correct? ANd whats up with that weird return where the longer timeout shows up first. Is something else going on? IS this a bad way of illustrating async in this piece of code? Is there a better way?